# Usage Reports of SharePoint 2013 site are showing empty data. Yet Timerjobs are running properly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, reports, site-usage

I am working on SharePoint 2013 usage reports. And I need to check that at how many times the users have hit the SharePoint 2013 SSRS reports in the document library on monthly and daily basis. I have checked all the timer jobs are working in a right way and at right time interval. Jobs such as "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import" and "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing" each are working as one at 5 min interval and the other one daily. Also the usage file is being generated in RequestUsage folder at the defined time intervals. Also I deleted the service application "Usage and Health Data Collection" and created it again using admin rights and checked the reports after 24 hours yet they are showing it as empty. Cannot understand what is the problem. New to usage reports.

Answer (score 0):

Niranjan, I'm just assuming that you had the same problem that I had with usage reporting when I moved from native to integrated SSRS. You can't monitor the document library for use you have to query the SSRS tables. Try some sql like

```
SELECT 
RIGHT( [ItemPath], 
    LEN([ItemPath]) - PATINDEX('%/sites/yoursite/ReportingLibrary/%' ,[ItemPath]) - 40
    ) AS Name,
      [UserName],
    COUNT(*) AS ExecutionCount,
    SUM(TimeDataRetrieval) AS TimeDataRetrievalSum,
    SUM(TimeProcessing) AS TimeProcessingSum,
    SUM(TimeRendering) AS TimeRenderingSum,
    SUM(ByteCount) AS ByteCountSum,
    SUM([RowCount]) AS RowCountSum,
    min(TimeStart) as FirstDate,
    max(TimeEnd) as LastDate
  FROM [ReportingService_databasename].[dbo].[ExecutionLog3]
  WHERE itemPath Like ''%/sites/yoursite/ReportingLibrary/%' 
            and RequestType = 'Interactive'
            and ItemAction = 'Render'
    GROUP BY  [ItemPath],[UserName]
ORDER BY
    [ItemPath],[UserName]
```

I hope this is of assistance to you. ExecutionLog3 is a very useful view in the Reporting Services database and there are a few more

Comment: No no, what I need is the graph to be shown and the records to be shown in the tables in the excelsheet of popularity trends. Of the site as well as of the library item.